# SQL Server DBCC not displaying output

Tags: sql-server-2008, dbcc

I am trying to use DBCC to see page information on a table.  When I run

```
DBCC page (master, 1, 1, 0)
GO
```

I get

> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your
>   system administrator.

in SSMS's Messages window.

I do not see output of DBCC.  Do I have to pass some flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default output is to the errorlog. You need to enable trace flag 3604 as described in this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/10/625659.aspx?Redirected=true) to redirect the output.

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604) -- turns on flag 3604 for your session
DBCC PAGE (master, 1, 1, 0);
DBCC TRACEOFF(3604) -- turns off 3604 for your session

DBCC TRACEON (3604, -1) -- turns on flag 3604 globally
DBCC PAGE (master, 1, 1, 0);
DBCC TRACEOFF(3604, –1) -- turns off 3604 globally
```